# Wine applications are not removed after uninstalling wine

Tags: software-installation, wine

[image: Lots of excel showing]

How can I remove all these excel from "other applications"?. There are also lots of Word and PowerPoint things which doesn't work.Since I have removed Wine, but still doesn't go. Please help...I have used synaptic manager to remove wine and also checked with terminal. In terminal however , says it virtual packages can't be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to eOS SE. Please execute this following commands in your terminal,

```
rm -r ~/.wine
rm -r ~/.local/share/applications/wine
rm ~/.local/share/applications/wine*
```